# Angular2 handle RouterOutlet: Cannot read property '_outlets' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I use angular2 v2.1.2, I wants to check router before load page.
After login, If user type url `/login`, my app will navigate to `HomePage`
If I don't `login`, I can not access to any page without login.

**My issue is:** If I open two tab on one browser: 
 
`Tab one`: login, and go to account page.
`Tab two`: login, then logout. Then back to `tab one` and reload page => an error occurs `TypeError: Cannot read property '_outlets' of undefined`.
How can I fix it

I have `Routes`

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
    {path: "login", component: LoginComponent},
    {path: "home", component: HomeComponent},
    {path: "accounts", component: AccountsComponent},
    {path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: '**', component: HomeComponent}
]);
```

And LoggedInRouterOutlet Directive

```
import { Directive, ComponentRef, ResolvedReflectiveProvider, Injectable, ComponentFactoryResolver, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, RouterOutlet, RouterOutletMap, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
@Directive({
    selector: 'router-outlet'
})

export class LoggedInRouterOutlet extends RouterOutlet {
    activate(activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, loadedResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, loadedInjector: Injector, providers: ResolvedReflectiveProvider[], outletMap: RouterOutletMap) {
        let isLogin = Storage.checkLogin(),
            loginComponents = ["login", "chooseAccount"],
            isPublic = activatedRoute.data.value.isPublic;

        if (isLogin) {
            if (_.includes(loginComponents, path)) {
                //navigate to HomePage if enter /login 
                location.href = '#/home';
            } else {
                return super.activate(activatedRoute, loadedResolver, loadedInjector, providers, outletMap);
            }
        } else {
            if (!_.includes(loginComponents, path)) {
                //navigate to LoginPage if enter /home, ...
                location.href = '#/login';
            } else {
                return super.activate(activatedRoute, loadedResolver, loadedInjector, providers, outletMap);
            }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Why are you not using guards https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#guards? Using `@Injectable()` when there is already `@Component()`, `@Directive()`, or `@Pipe()` is redundant.

Comment: Because I don't know it, I seen one sample when I search, thanks @GünterZöchbauer I will try

Comment: Thanks @GünterZöchbauer, it work well for me :)

Comment: Hi @GünterZöchbauer, one more question: how can I auto set `canActivate:[CanActivateCustom]` for all routes?

Comment: You can create a parent route (without a component) and only your current routes as child route, and add the guard to the parent route.

Comment: I tried with : `[ { path: '', canActivate: [AuthGuard], children: [`define router`]  } ]`. And an error `Cannot read property 'path' of undefined` occurs

Comment: Sorry, no idea.

Comment: ok, thanks @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: @Sophia The issue is with your name selector.

Comment: sorry @RomanC, I just design one sample, this is my code `[ { path: '', canActivate: [CanActivateCustom], children: [ `define router` ] } ]`. Any idea for my issue?

Comment: sorry @GünterZöchbauer and @RomanC, I have rechecked my code, and when I use `[ { path: '', canActivate: [CanActivateCustom], children: [define router] } ]`, it doesn't show error `Cannot read property 'path' of undefined`, but It doesn't call `CanActivateCustom` too, cannot apply `canActive` for all routers

Comment: Do you have a property `path` in `CanActivateCustom`?

Comment: As @RomanC said, you're accessing `path` in your code, but there doesn't seem to be a `path` declared anywhere.

Comment: yes, I used `route.url[0].path` in `CanActivateCustom`, so sometimes `route.url[0]` is undefined. I fixed it, but `canActive ` still cannot apply for all routers. I added `canActivate: [CanActivateCustom]` for each router to resolve. Thanks @GünterZöchbauer and @RomanC for your support :)

Comment: What does "still cannot apply for all routers" mean exactly. You can also try `canActivateChildren`. (I don't have deep knowledge about guards because they are not available in Dart)

Comment: "still cannot apply for all routers" mean all routers don't see `CanActivateCustom`. I tried `canActivateChildren`, but doesn't work too. I think I have to add `CanActivateCustom` for each router. Please let me know when you have any idea, thanks @GünterZöchbauer.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean with "all routers don't see CanActivateCustom" either. Why would routers need to see them?

Comment: it mean: the `canActivate: [CanActivateCustom]` doesn't auto set for all routers via `[ { path: '', canActivate: [CanActivateCustom], children: [  all routers ] } ]`, that I have to set `canActivate: [CanActivateCustom]` for router by router, if I wants to check router before load component.

Comment: Oh, I resolved my issue. I need to create `export class CanActivateCustom implements CanActivate, CanActivateChild `, and write function `canActivateChild()` to use `[ { path: '', canActivateChild: [CanActivateCustom], children: [allRoutes] } ]`. It work well for me :D